# Elegantly spread single Django model across multiple tables?

Tags: django, django-models, multi-table-inheritance

There's plenty of document and discussion for having multiple models share fields in a parent class/table using "concrete" or "multi-table" inheritance:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    ...

class Restaurant(Place):
    ...
```

However, I can't find much on the inverse use-case: splitting the fields of a single model across multiple tables to save the cost of loading wide columns except when you actually need them.

Consider the following scenario:

```
class Person_Profile(models.Model):
    ...lots of fields...

class Person_Preferences(models.Model):
    ...lots of fields...

class Person(Person_Profile, Person_Preferences):
    ...small set of core fields...
```

What works:

- When you create a Person, the other two objects are automatically created and linked for you.
- You can access profile and preference fields directly on Person.  (`person.some_field`)

The only thing I'm missing is how to elegantly control when Django loads the fields from the parent table, since currently, loading a Person with `p = Person.objects.first()` results in all three tables being joined and selected by default.

##### UPDATE

I went looking for how Django let's you express selecting a subset of fields and arrived at the QuerySet methods [defer()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#defer) and [only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#only), along with the suggestion there about using an unmanaged model as a facade to conveniently load a subset of fields:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pref1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

class SkinnyPerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myapp_person'
```

Haven't reach a conclusion yet, but this method has a lot of appeal right now.

Comment: why don't you user  one to one relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitted model - This is a good solution only if you don't understand the DataManagers/Queryset idea.

The splitting fields on the models is good approach, if you use `Meta.abstract = True`. if you create two real сlasses only to add together all fields in child class - you loose many time with joins on every ask in DB.

more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

In `QuerySet` you can define many methods. After that you can chain methods together.

```
class Person_Profile(models.Model):
    Meta:
        abstract = True

    ...lots of fields...

class Person_Preferences(models.Model):
    Meta:
        abstract = True

    ...lots of fields...

class Person(Person_Profile, Person_Preferences):
    ...small set of core fields...
    objects = PersonQueryset.as_manager()  # in old django PersonDataManager()
```

How might `PersonDataManager` or `PersonQuerySet` look like:

```
class PersonQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def onlySpecialFields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.only(*my_special_only_list)

    def deferSpecialFields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.defer(*my_special_defer_list)

    def skinnyPersons(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.only('name')
```

How you can use it:

```
SkinnyPersons_List = Person.objects.filter(name=something).skinnyPersons()
# after that
FirstSkinnyPerson = SkinnyPersons_List.first()

# somethere in code
LastSkinnyPerson = Person.objects.skinnyPersons().last()
```

Pros:

- content type is always the same
- you don't have problem with generic objects
- you work with the same ._meta, .app_label and .model_name
- you don't have any new model, which you are dont need.
- you use idea of django querysets

cons:

- not found

Comment: A great answer - thanks.  Admittedly, querysets and managers are two areas I'm still weak on.  My studies so far have been focused more on model definitions and migration-related challenges.

Comment: you are welcome. i have a talks on django con EU 2022 and on django con US 2022. We can talk there

Comment: Only feature I still long for is a QS method that can undo a previous call to defer() - like undefer().  That way I have the option of making the default behavior the deferring of large fields, but have a QS method that undoes the defer when you want the full model.

Comment: undefer = defer(None,) more here: django.db.models.query.py row 1223

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!  PS-I checked, and it is indeed mentioned in my version of the docs, I must have missed it:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#defer